# Help verifying proof that for any commutative ring $R$ and $j \in R$, the subset $jR$ is an Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $j \in R$. We wish to prove that $JR \equiv \{ jr : r \in R \}$ is an ideal of $R$. To prove that $jR$ is an ideal, we need to verify that $(jR, 0, +)$ is an abelian group, and that $jR$ is closed under multiplication by the entire ring.

This seems elementary, but I have this paranoid feeling that I'm missing something, so I'd appreciate it if someone verified this for me!

To prove that $(jR, 0, +)$ an abelian group:

- $0 = j0 \in jR$, hence identity is satisfied
- for all $r_1, r_2 \in R$, $jr_1 + jr_2 = j(r_1 + r_2) \in jR$, hence closure is satisfied
- for all $r \in R,  jr \in jR \implies  j(-r_1) \in jR$, hence $jR$ closed under inverses.
- commutativity of $+$ follows since the ring $(R, +)$ is a commutative ring.

To prove that it's closed under multiplication under the entire ring:

- Let $jr \in jR$. We pick any $s \in R$ and show that multiplying this element keeps us in $jR$:  $s(jr) = (jr) s = j (rs) \in jR$.

Hence, $jR$ is indeed an ideal of $R$.

Comment: I see no problems with your verification

Comment: Neither do I; well done, ***endorsed, +1!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to show that $(jR, 0, +)$ forms a group which is often used is the general observation that for *any* group $G$ and non-empty subset

$S \subset G, \tag 1$

$S$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if

$a, b \in S \Longrightarrow ab^{-1} \in S; \tag 2$

it is easy to see that this holds if $S$ is a subgroup, since then $b^{-1} \in S$ etc; going the other way, (2) yields

$a \in S \Longrightarrow e = aa^{-1} \in S, \tag 3$

so $S$ contains the identity element; then

$e, a \in S \Longrightarrow a^{-1} = ea^{-1} \in S, \tag 4$

so $S$ contains inverses of all its elements; finally,

$a, b \in S \Longrightarrow b^{-1} \in S \Longrightarrow ab = a(b^{-1})^{-1} \in S, \tag 5$

and $S$ is closed under the group operation.  So we see that $S$ must be a subgroup of $G$.

We may apply this to $Rj$, since

$aj, bj \in Rj \Longrightarrow aj - bj = (a - b)j \in Rj, \tag 6$

and thus $(Rj, 0, +)$ is an (abelian) subgroup of $(R, 0, +)$.

$OE\Delta$.